# Effective way to change_column from nullable to non-null using migrations?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which has several nullable columns which, due to additional work, requires some of the columns to now be non-null.

The problem I have is there are foreign key constraints. There were optional associations which are now not optional.

I have a lot of data with blank associations which require an association. Advice?

From:

```
  t.integer :user_id,  :null => true
  t.integer :place_id, :null => true
```

To:

```
change_column :hotel, :user_id, :integer,     :null => false
change_column :hotel, :place_id, :integer,    :null => false
```

I know I can use the :default => val option, but is there anything else I should take into account during this switch?

Comment: What do you plan to do with these "optional FKs that are no longer optional"? Do you need to invent a placeholder that you can use for all of them at once? Create one placeholder for each?

Comment: @muistooshort I'm the one asking the same question ;)

Comment: We can't really help you figure out your business requirements, this isn't businessanalysts.stackexchange.com :) The programming side of things is pretty straight forward here once you know what the business requirements are.

Comment: @muistooshort what? No. I'm not asking someone to figure out my business requirements. Will they also write all my future business requirements? I am simply asking if there is an effective or preferred way to approach the above scenario. That's it. Forget about my business requirements. Lars Haugseth understands the question perfectly. Not sure why you don't.

Comment: @muistooshort " The programming side of things is pretty straight forward" This is also a bit presumptuous don't you think? I'm certainly not asking this question despite knowing the answer am I?? It isn't straight forward to me..hence my question. I think you should just go bother somebody else in the comments to their question if you haven't an answer.

Comment: But you have to answer the "what about the existing NULLs" question first. Once that's answered then the programming is simple: create the necessary new objects, attach them to replace the NULLs, and add the `:null => false` migration. I don't have an answer because your question is incomplete, I'm commenting to try and help you clarify your question.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth look where that got us ;)

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, I think maybe you just don't understand the extent of ignorance. I am asking because, as stated in my question: "I know I can use the :default => val option, but is there anything else I should take into account during this switch?". Meaning, I have never done such a thing, and maybe there is a big red flag during this kind of task where I need to take some other things into account.

Comment: You have to decide what to do with the existing NULLs: do you want to use one placeholder for all of them? Separate placeholders for each? Some combination? I don't think `:default => val` is what you want, that will apply to future entries and could hide bugs. You're going to create a certain number of placeholders to take the place of the old NULLs, hook them up to replace the NULLs, and then do a `:null => false` migration. The hardest part is figuring out what to do with the existing NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate migration that links associated data to existing records, and make sure that migration is named so that it is run *before* the one where you add the `:null => false` constraints.